# With matplotlib, how to make legend opaque for diagram, but background-transparent in the end?

Tags: html, matplotlib

I have a problem with the background of matplotlib figures when embedded into HTML pages of various background colors.

I save the figures as PNG or SVG files and embed them into HTML with the img tag. That works; I can see the diagram on the webpage.

The background of the figure, as displayed on the HTML page, shall be the same as the background of the page, so I make the figure transparent with `fig.savefig(filename, transparent=True)`.

That works nicely on the main part of the figure, but not on the legend. This is because I want the legend to hide all diagram content behind it (be opaque for the diagram, see below), but later when embedded into the page, the background of the legend needs to allow the background color of the HTML page to shine through. Below are examples. Of course, these are no real diagrams. They are just for illustrating the transparency problem.

Undesired:
grey HTML background, transparent diagram, opaque legend:
`ax.legend(..., framealpha=1)`

[image: grey HTML background, transparent diagram, opaque legend]
Fig. 1

Even worse:
grey HTML background, transparent diagram, transparent legend:
`ax.legend(..., framealpha=0)`

[image: grey HTML background, transparent diagram, transparent legend]
Fig. 2

How it should look:
Using the trick to make the legend opaque and use grey face color, I can achieve the desired look on the grey background:
`ax.legend(..., facecolor='lightgrey', framealpha=1)`

[image: desired colors on the grey background]
Fig. 3

Not portable:
But then again, when on a page with white background, I get the same problem as in Fig. 1, just with swapped colors:
[image: same problem like in Fig. 1, just with swapped colors]
Fig. 4

Using this workaround would force me to generate the figures separately for all HTML background colors, and I would need to regenerate figures when changing the background color of an HTML page.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Potentially, you could try getting the outline of the legend as a `Path` and use it to clip all content of the axes (`clip_path`).

Comment: You are looking to make a particular layer opaque the background layer and yet still be transparent. Is it correct?

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi yes, that's correct, like the title of the question says: how to make legend opaque for diagram, but background-transparent in the end? - it's the classic "problem" that you can't use a transparent paint to make something look transparent. A transparent paint just doesn't paint anything (see Fig. 2: transparent legend). This subtlety must exist in various current drawing frameworks.